# How to prevent input using scanf from overflowing?

Tags: c, integer, overflow, scanf

I'm relatively new to C and would like to know how to prevent an overflow from input...

So for example, I have:

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

Where a is an integer.

So what I could I do to prevent someone from entering a number that's larger than max integer? Due to the constraints of the problem I'm working on, you HAVE to use `scanf`. How do I go about restricting the input?

Comment: Use `scanf` to read a string and then parse it yourself ?

Comment: Theoretically you can see if errno is ERANGE for an out-of-range error. However this is not standard specified for scanf. See http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf `''C89 and C99 and POSIX.1-2001 standards do not specify the ERANGE error ''` In other words, you should use `strtol` if you need to read an integer while also having the ability to check for overflow.

Comment: If you *must* use scanf, one simple way would be to read a `double` instead using scanf (which has a larger range), do your own range check, and then cast the result to an `int` if it meets your criteria. This will work without loss of information so long as your valid integer range is not too large.

Comment: @Brandin: The ANSI-C spec does say that a sequence of digits is matched and then converted with the strtol function.  So if the value is too large for a long, you will get an ERANGE.  However, it is unclear what happens if it is too large for an int but fits in a long.

Answer (score 2):

It is very challenging to *prevent* user input.
There is no magic hand to reach out and stop the user from beating away at the keyboard.

But code can limit what it reads.

1. `scanf()` is tough to limit.  It may not set `errno` on overflow.  Code can limit the number of `char` to say 9.  That's a first step but one can not enter values like "1000000000" or "00000000000000001".

   ```
   // Assume INT_MAX = 2,147,483,647.
   scanf("%9d", &a);
   ```
2. A pedantic method would use `fgetc()`.  An `unsigned` method follows.  `int` takes a bit more.

   ```
   unsigned a = 0;
   int ch = fgetc(stdin);
   while (isspace(ch)) {
     ch = fgetc(stdin);
   }
   while (isdigit(ch)) {
     ch -= '0';
     if (a >= UINTMAX/10 && (a > UINTMAX/10 || ch > UINTMAX%10)) {
       a = UINTMAX;
       break;  // overflow detected.
     }
     a = a*10 + ch;
     ch = fgetc(stdin);
   }
   ungetc(ch, stdin);  // Put back `ch` as it was not used.
   ```
3. But I prefer to change the goal and simply tell the user again, even if it means reading in more characters.

   ```
   // 0:success or EOF
   int Read_int(const char *prompt, int *dest, int min, int max) {
     for (;;) {
       char buf[(sizeof(int)*3 + 3)*2];  // 2x generous buffer
       fputs(prompt, stdout);
       if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
         return EOF;
       }
       char *endptr;
       errno = 0;
       long l = strtol(buf, &endptr, 10);
       // no conversion or junk at the end ....
       if (buf == endptr || *endptr != '\n') {
         continue;
       }
       if (!errno && l >= min && l <= max) {
        *dest = (int) l;
        return 0; // success
       }
     }
   }  

   // Sample usage
   int a;
   Read_int("Enter an `int`\n", &a, INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
   ```