# C: Function for user input validation

Tags: c, function, validation, input

I am learning C at university and have to write several codes for it.

I would like to write a function for user input validation (scanf()). It should be a seperate function (not in main()) and have certain Properties. e.g.:
     User input has to be an integer and between 0 and 100.
     User input has to be a prime number.
     User input has to be a specific letter.
     ...
     ...
I already got something like this, but the problem is, that it is very specific and i have to rewrite it every time for the specific code.

```
while (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 1 || n > 100) {

    while (getchar() != '\n');
        printf("Wrong Input !\n\nn:");
}
```

I'd like to use the same function for several "programms" with each different requirements. Also i'd like to be able to add new "parameter requirements" to the function.
Help really appreciated!

Comment: Note: when `scanf("%d", &n) ` returns `EOF`, code has potential UB and likely is an infinite loop.  Consider `scanf("%d"...` may return `0,1,EOF`.

Comment: [Sample solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21666135/2410359)

Comment: Ok thx for that info, but its not quite the point of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a validation function that does the specific work. See the following sample code that illustrates this approach. Hope it helps somehow.

```
void inputWithValidation(int *n, int(*isValidFunc)(int)) {

    while (scanf("%d", n) != 1 || !isValidFunc(*n)) {

        while (getchar() != '\n');
        printf("Wrong Input !\n\nn:");
    }

}

int isBetween10And100(int n) {
    return n >= 0 && n <= 100;
}

int isPositive(int n) {
    return n >= 0;
}

int main() {

    int n;

    inputWithValidation(&n, isBetween10And100);

    inputWithValidation(&n, isPositive);

}
```

Comment: Ty for your efforts! That is a great idea and it helped me a lot, but what if input has to have more than one attribute. EG: input has to be positive and even. If i use it twice, it just rewrites the variable.

Comment: I could use int isPositiveAndEven(int n) {
    return (n >= 0 && (n%2 == 0)); but as there would be too many possible ways to do this, it takes away the sense of this function(saving time).

Comment: With an initial end-of-file, code is UB when `isValidFunc(*n)` is called.  With a rare file error, it is also UB.  Best not to use `*n` unless `scanf("%d", n)` returns 1.